# Update only diffs in a $scope.arrayOfObjects - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like this:

```
$scope.charts = [
   {
      status: {
         success: 2,
         errors: 0
      }
   }
];
```

After receive a few data from the server, I have to update the charts array. Supposing that the new array is almost the same than the current, how can I update only the property that is different, instead of make the template recalculate all again?

```
newArray = [
   {
      status: {
         success: 2,
         errors: 1
      }
   }
];
```

Today I'am doing something like this:

```
$scope.charts = newArray;
```

But even if the array has no difference, the template flashes, like if new date was received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you're using `ng-repeat` with this array, adding [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) with an ID (or the $index, if it stays the same) will prevent the rerendering of existing items.

generally speaking, always add `track by` to an `ng-repeat`, in order to minimize performance issues.

Comment: It's worth noting that `track by` overrides the default behavior of tracking the elements by the actual object reference with your specified behavior. That's the key to *why* this solution works.

Comment: Thank you Eran and @mhodges it's what I was looking for.